# django celery - multiprocessing

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Django celery for my project requirements.
How can i do the multiprocessing of two queues that uses a single worker?
I don't want one queue to wait for the task in other queue to finish.

Please advice

Comment: not quite clear. you want 2 jobs to be processed by a single worker and you want them to be independent from each other and processed in paralel? what actually do you want?

Comment: thanks for the comment. Actually i need two queues in a single worker and need the two queues to be processed in parallel..

Comment: @SkariaArun This is an impassable.

Comment: you want them to be in a queue that is a finish-to-start logic simply cannot be parallel, which is a start-to-start logic. it's not logical.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you need only a single worker to be processing two queues? It would be pretty easy to spin up two workers that each watch one of the queues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [concurrenc](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency)y of `>1` ? Like so:

`celeryd -c 5`

That should start a worker with 5 processes that can work on things in parallel.